# I don't know what voltage to use for my Arduino Uno

Tags: arduino, voltage, arduino-uno

Specifications:

- It's a 100% Arduino pro micro Compatible Board.
- Chip: ATmega32u4
- Board Mode: LEDNARDO R3
- Operating frequency: 16MHz
- Working voltage: 5V
- Input voltage: 7-12V
- Digital IO port: 20
- PWM channel: 7
- Analog input: 12
- Maximum current of 5V digital/analog port: 40mA
- Maximum current of 3.3 V digital/analog port: 50 mA

What do I feed the Arduino Uno? 7-12V or 5V?

[image]

Comment: Feed it with what you like. 7-12 V through the regulator input, or 5 V through the 5 V input.

Comment: Downvoting and voting to close a beginners question. What a warm welcome they get on ee.se

Comment: @Neil_UK I still wouldn't feed it with unregulated 5v though 5v pin, instead I'd do 5v though Vin or even 12v through the same pin. Then again, I really only use USB, I don't deal much with the care and feeding of Arduinos.

Answer (score 4):

You can supply it either with

- 5V via USB
- 7-12V via the barrel jack, or
- 7-12V via the Vin pin

According to [this source](https://store-usa.arduino.cc/products/arduino-uno-rev3) (first google result for "arduino how supply voltage").

Answer (score 2):

The working voltage is meant to tell you what the regulator outputs and what the electronics works at (such as the MCU). That in turn helps you know what the I/O voltage levels are. It also means that if there is a power pin that bypasses the regulator to feed the logic directly, then it needs to be a good, steady, clean 5V.

The input voltage of 7-12V would be through the regulator.